# Apostol problem : find $T(e_2-e_1)$ and determine the nullity and rank of $T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem taken from ***Apostol  calculas*** Volume $2$ . Page no :$ 50$  excercise $2.12$ ,Problem $.10$

Let $V$ and $W$ be linear spaces, each with dimension $2$ and each with basis $(e_1 , e_2)$. Let $T: V \rightarrow  W$ be a linear transformation such that $T(e_1 + e_2) = 3e_1 + 9e_2, T(3e_1 + 2e_2) = 7e_1 + 23e_2.$

Compute $T(e_2-e_1)$ and determine the nullity and rank of $T$.

My attempt : Given  $$T(e_1 + e_2) = 3e_1 + 9e_2$$

$$T(e_1 +e_2)= T(e_1) +T(e_2)= 3e_1+ 9e_2\tag1$$

and $$T(3e_1 + 2e_2) = 7e_1 + 23e_2$$
$$T(3e_1 +2e_2)= 3T(e_1) +2T(e_2)= 7e_1+ 23e \tag2$$

Multilpy  $(1)$ by $2$ and solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have  $T(e_1)=7e_1 +5 e_2$ and $T(e_2)= 14 e_1 + 19 e_2$

$T(e_2-e_1)= T(e_2)-T(e_1) = 14e_1 + 19e_2 -7e_1-5e_2= 7e_2 +14 e_1$

To find the nullity and rank of T  we have

$T=\begin{bmatrix}7&5\\14 &19 \end{bmatrix}^T=\begin{bmatrix}7&14\\5 &19 \end{bmatrix}$

Rank$(T)= 2$ and nullity$( T)=0$

Is its true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit : your proceeds ok, but calculations are wrong.
$T(e_1 + e_2) = T(e_1)+T(e_2)= 3e_1 + 9e_2, T(3e_1 + 2e_2) = 3T(e_1)+2T(e_2) =7e_1 + 23e_2.$

After solving, $T(e_1) = e_1+5e_2 , T(e_2)=2e_1+4e_2 $

So, matrix $T$ be with respect to the basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$ , $T=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\5 &4 \end{bmatrix}$